# CORS header has information but Angular js $http.get does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, cors

I am using angular js to consume a rest service . The rest api does return  required headers but I get

```
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
```

and in mozilla I get

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the   remote resource at http://testurl.com:8081/v1/users. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).
```

error

API header returns gives

```
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Authorization
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: x-requested-with
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate 
Pragma: no-cache 
Expires: 0 
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Application-Context: application:8081
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2016 14:57:20 GMT
```

Below is http request

```
 $http({
         method: 'post',
         url: 'http://testurl.com/v1/users',
         data    : data
         }).then(function successCallback(response) {
         object.sucess=true;
         object.massage=response;
         console.log('success');
         }, function errorCallback(response) {
         object.sucess=true;
         object.massage=response;

         });
```

Am I doing something wrong or the problem is in header .

Comment: You aren't showing the status code for the response headers you've quoted, but the browser says it is 401 (meaning Unauthorized), so you need to address that on the server.

Comment: My api works fine from rest client but when I try to use it from  angular js app I get this . Server is fine from mobile or rest api

Comment: The *server* is returning the 401.  Note that the code you posted is doing a `POST`, not a `GET`.

Comment: *"api works fine from rest client but when I try to use it from angular js app I get this"*. So all you need to do is to compare headers in both cases. Quite straightforward.

Comment: "My api works fine from rest client but when I try to use it from angular js app I get" — Well, obviously! You aren't going to be making the preflight request that the browser says you are responding incorrectly to if you aren't using a regular web app!

Comment: My app is hosted in local host but the api is another server . what am I doing wrong exactly ? @Quentin

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoman — I don't know. You haven't shared the code, hosted on "another server", which responds to the preflight OPTIONS request.

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoman CORS is browser problem, i.e. Same-origin policy
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: yes I know . we can change  CORS by adding CORS header .. I have added cors header still it does not work @A.T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution . It was missing preflight OPTIONS. I had to add those in my back end . Now it works fine .

Answer (score 1):

As I read your problem i have also faced this problems and this problem can be resolved from server side as well from client side also by creating proxy server. In server side you need to allow the ip of your system.

Usually their are 3 solutions as i know.

1).
Example: As What i do while creating web service in NodeJs(API):

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://hostname.com');
// Request methods you wish to allow
// You can write * also for allowing to access that url from all systems which is not done usually for security purposes
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```

Then you can run get as well as post request too.

2). You can also create proxy server to handle that post and put reuests so that communication to that api will be constant

3). You can install CORS plugin in your chrome browser and enable it and you can query to the server side.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Comment: your answers are invalid . 2.I have added those headers see my headers 2. proxy server is not a option since it undermines  performance and then 3. My api will be exposed to everyone so I can not ask all the users to add crome plugin . and yes I tried it does not work :( @Hermant

Answer (score 0):

You have put `Authorization` as an allowed header. This is incorrect, instead you need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` which will allow this header.

This separate setting controls the browser sending cookies as well as `Authorization` header

Comment: Also worth trying, set the allow origin header with a specific value instead of *, I have had problems with that before. You need to take the origin header that the browser is sending and return it